# Prior to COVID-19, had any country fiscally targeted unvaccinated individuals?

Tags: taxes, healthcare, covid-19, history

Upon reading that [Quebec may impose a health tax on unvaccinated Canadians](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-59960689), I wondered the following: Prior to COVID-19, had any country fiscally targeted unvaccinated individuals?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it may not age well. If the answer is "no" now, it may change later. If there's a list now - it may grow/change/shrink later.

Comment: @littleadv the question states "Prior to COVID-19", so the answer won't change in the future.

Comment: Does public school access count as "fiscally targeting"? In California unvaccinated children are not allowed into public education system for example.

Comment: @littleadv let's only consider direct financial consequences.

Comment: Are human slaves within the parameters of the question? If so there is a possible yes, but it is gruesome.

Comment: Perhaps better subject matter for *History* or *Politics.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "fiscally targeted", but in Slovakia, refusing compulsory vaccination(s) was an offence (*priestupok* – infraction or misdemeanor, whatever is the correct equivalent) and could be fined up to 331€.

[Source](https://www.uvzsr.sk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3747:mz-sr-uvz-sr-ochrana-zdravia-deti&catid=56:tlaove-spravy&Itemid=62) (discussing the plans to remove the fine and replace it by refusing public school access to unvaccinated children - ironically, the discussion is from the spring of 2019)

Answer (score 0):

Reddit user [CorrectlyKnown](https://www.reddit.com/user/CorrectlyKnown) [pointed me](https://redd.it/s1y2qm) to an interesting example from Australia: the [No Jab, No Pay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Jab,_No_Pay) tax policy.

> No Jab No Pay is an Australian policy initiative which withholds three state payments – Child Care Benefit, the Child Care Rebate and a portion of the fortnightly Family Tax Benefit part A per child – for parents of children under 20 years of age who are not fully immunised or on a recognised catch-up schedule.